# Mongoose query exact field

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm working with a collection made with the following (abbreviated) schema:

```
username: String,
social: {
    github: {
        id: String,
        username: String,
        token: String
    },
    linkedin: {
        id: String,
        token: String,
        tokenSecret: String
    }
}
```

I have the following query `UserModel.findOne({'username': req.body.username}...` which I want to return *only* the documents with the matching `username` field and *not* the `social.github.username` field. The query is returning documents matching both fields though.

How do I fix the query?

Comment: What you're doing already is correct. Something else must be going on here.

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
UserModel.findOne({
   'username': req.body.username, 
   'social.github.username': {$ne: req.body.username}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out `req.body.username` was `undefined` and that's why the query wasn't working.